# Meaning of IN in Perl

Tags: perl

I tried googling and searching SO, but as you can imagine, looking for *in* doesn't provide me with any useful information other than ***in*** Perl.

I came across this script:

```
($script,$xpaths,$treebanks)=@ARGV;

open(IN,$xpaths);
while (<IN>) {
    # Some code
}
```

but I don't understand what is going on with that IN. What does it mean? I understand if this is a stupid question but as I pointed out, search attempts returned nothing fruitful.

Comment: Typeglobs like `IN` are inherently global, so it's a bad practice to use them. You should use `open(my $IN, ...)` (and thus `while (<$IN>)`) instead. /// You should also always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`.

Comment: @Arc676: Please consider deleting your comment. It's obviously guesswork and mostly unhelpful.

Comment: Language documentation almost always explains the parameters accepted by built-in functions. The [documentation for open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) explains this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IN` has no special meaning, it is just a sequence of characters, much like a variable name. It's short for `*IN`, a typeglob (or glob for short). You needn't worry too much about knowing what that is beyond knowing it can store a file handle.

You defined it as the name of a file handle when you said `open(IN,$xpaths);` and then you read from it when you said `while (<IN>)`.

---

See also [the documentation for open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> An older style is to use a bareword as the filehandle, as
>
> ```
> open(FH, "<", "input.txt")
>    or die "cannot open < input.txt: $!";
> ```
>
> Then you can use FH as the filehandle, in close FH and  and so on.
>   Note that it's a global variable, so this form is not recommended in
>   new code.

Modern Perl would use a lexically scoped variable, and the three-argument form of open, instead.

```
open(my $in, "<", $xpaths) or die $!;
while (<$in>) {
```

Comment: Might be worth expanding on "whats going on" in terms of the while loop reading line by line.

Answer (score 0):

IN is the filehandle that is created with open

Comment: A bareword filehandle, which is global in scope, and their use is discouraged in favour of lexical variable handles.